# Mongo fatal error

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using php and mongo db... I want to get user details using userkey which is a unique

key.. My mongo query is :

```
       $obj= $mongo->user;
       $filter = array(
            'userkey'=>$value
        );
        $exist = $obj->findone($filter);
```

When i execute this query, am getting error as ..

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in line 5
```

ie $exist = $obj->findone($filter); shows error

How to solve this problem

Can someone help me plz...

Comment: what line of the code shown is causing the max execution time? Also see http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: @PatrickLorio:  $exist = $obj->findone($filter);.... this line shows error

Comment: And what shows up in your MongoDB log file?

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your call on on PHP.

You should have $mongoobject->basename->collectionname then a call with findOne (take care of uppercase)

Comment: My guess is there is something wrong with initializing your $mongo object

Answer (score 0):

Can you get any mongo queries to work, or is it just this one that fails?  It could be something with your connection to the database.  I believe that "findone()" will wait forever on a stalled connection. I would recommend using "find()" instead, and giving it a low timeout, like 100ms.  This may help.

$cursor = $collection->find($query,$fields)->timeout(100);
$record = $cursor->getNext();

Obviously, you will want to wrap this in a try/catch block to capture the timeout exception. Be sure to use the latest mongo drivers (1.2.10 or better), because earlier versions of the php mongo drivers would segfault on a connection timeout.